# lightning:formattedAddress not opening the exact location in Google Maps in Android

Tags: lightning-aura-components, android, salesforce-mobile-app

We have an implementation where we are displaying an address on a lightning aura component using [`lightning:formattedAddress`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedAddress/documentation) in Salesforce Mobile App. The component itself works fine and renders the address as expected with the link to be able to navigate to the exact location as mentioned in the address.

However, we observed that upon clicking the address link, it works fine on iOS devices where Google Maps open with the exact location as provided in the address BUT it does not work as expected on Android devices. On Android devices, upon click of the link, it simply opens the Google Map with the User's current location and not the exact location as specified in the address.

Has anyone experienced anything similar to this? Is there any specific setting either on the component or the Android device that needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with all our other issues on Mobile recently, we had to reach to Salesforce support on this one too.

It turns out to be an issue in the Android Google Maps implementation. Salesforce support responded back to us with the details and that Salesforce has now opened a ticket to Google (first time I have seen this happening). If you at all are facing this issue in your implementation, this should help.

Response from Salesforce support:

> This is a Google Map app issue - the problem was reproduced by R&D within Gmail app. The Google Map app intercepts the url which should be opened by the web browser which results in the app ignoring the location information and displays the location previously displayed

[Issue link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145149459) that was raised to Google from Salesforce.